# In Symfony 5, the command doctrine:database:create outputs an error instead of creating a database for test environment

Tags: symfony, doctrine, environment-variables

I'm learning Symfony 5 at [Symfony 5: The Fast Track](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/index.html) and I'm at the step [17.4 Working with a Test Database](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/17-tests.html).

I can read from the beginning of this section:

> ... the Symfony CLI automatically exposes the **DATABASE_URL**
> environment variable. **When APP_ENV is test**, like set when running
> PHPUnit, **it changes the database name from main to main_test** so
> that tests have their very own database.
>
> Before being able to run the test, **we need to “initialize” the test
> database** (create the database and migrate it):
>
> ```
> $ APP_ENV=test symfony console doctrine:database:create
> $ APP_ENV=test symfony console doctrine:migrations:migrate -n
> ```

My database name is `guestbook`, running under `MySql & Apache`, as specified in the `.env` file:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/guestbook?serverVersion=mariadb-10.4.19"
```

So, while I was expecting a database named `guestbook_test` to be created when I execute the command `symfony console doctrine:database:create`, it outputs the following error:

```
Could not create database `guestbook` for connection named default
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE DATABASE `guestbook`':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'guestbook'; database exists
exit status 1
```

To make sure the environment is "test", I, first, tried these two ways:

- In the `.env` file: `APP_ENV=test`
- In the `.env.local` file: `APP_ENV=test`

But, I got the same error.

When I displayed the content of environment variable `APP_ENV` from a controller, using `return new Response("APP_ENV = '" . getenv('APP_ENV') . "'");`, it displays a null value: `APP_ENV=''`.

So, I assigned the value `'test'` to `APP_ENV` in Real environment variables (for me, that was Windows/Paramaters/environment variables...etc). This once, the controller displays `APP_ENV='test'`, but I get always the same error, when I execute the Doctrine command: `symfony console doctrine:database:create`

I don't know what I'm missing !! Please, any help?

```
UPDATE ON: 07 June 2021 22:05
```

I, even tried assigning the value `test` to `APP_ENV` in `php.ini`; but, when I displayed this env var using: `symfony console debug:container --env-var=APP_ENV`, I got:

```
Symfony Container Environment Variables
=======================================

 // Displaying detailed environment variable usage matching APP_ENV

 None of the environment variables match this name.
```

It's, little bit, **strange** since I have this env var assigned every where (in `.env` file, `.env.local`, `php.ini` and in a `real env vars`) and this command says there is no env var called `APP_ENV` !

Comment: "Can't create database 'guestbook'; database exists" Think about what 'database exists' means.  And perhaps consider using a doctrine:database:drop command.

Comment: Indeed, guestbook database exists and it is the main one for me. But, the Symfony Fast Track says that, for test environment, an other database named {Database name}_test will be created via the command: doctrine:database:create

Comment: Did you actually try running 'APP_ENV=test symfony console doctrine:database:create' as the link suggests?

Comment: Yes, it outputs: `'APP_ENV' is not recognized as internal or external command ` !

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What helped in my case:

- create .env.local file
- copy the DATABASE_URL variable with db name suffixed with _test
- I also had to change db user to root, as my app db user didn't have permissions to create databases,